# How can one generate .out in Code Blocks in Ubuntu.?

Tags: linux, exe, codeblocks

I have just shifted to ubuntu. Earlier I used to write my code in Code Blocks for windows. Compile using it. But running the exe from the console as in  `abc.exe < input.in`. Hated giving output again & again. Following it in Ubuntu I installed CodeBlocks for Ubuntu but in linux as well it generates .exe and .o which do not works in linux according to my knowledge.
Also I know that I have to run like  `./abc.out < input.in` . So now I want code blocks to generate .out. If this is not possible please suggest Some other method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know how to name an executable while compiling it. If so, you can use the `-o <filename>` flag to `gcc(1)`:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", "hello world!");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o hello hello.c
$ ./hello
hello world!
$
```